# TaskCanceledException always break even on try-catch

Tags: c#, async-await, visual-studio-2022

This is on Windows 11, VS2022.
[image: TaskCanceledException always break expanded]
I already tried ticking it off from Exception settings. I also ticked off 'Just My Code'.
How do I prevent VS from breaking on this?

```
_taskCompletion // TaskCompletionSource<object>
```

EDIT:
This is using Xamarin Forms, .NET Standard 2.1, Android Emulator

Comment: is this a first-chance exception? does this actually throw (without being caught by one of the handlers) if you're not in the debugger? also: note, `TaskCanceledException : OperationCanceledException`, so you don't need the first `catch`

Comment: @JonasH I reuploaded a new image with expanded [ Exception Settings ].

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes this is first-chance from TaskCompletionSource.SetCanceled(). I tried removing the catch clauses and it actually throws and makes the app crash. I just tried catching OperationCanceledException to see if it solves it.

Comment: @JonasH Yes. This is from TaskCompletionSource.SetCanceled(). It actually goes to the catch clause if I put a break point.

Comment: @aeonblaire then... Turn off first-chance exceptions? This is purely a debugger thing

Comment: @MarcGravell using DebuggerNonUserCode?

Comment: yeah, I'd give that a go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using TaskCompletionSource.SetCanceled(). It was a private field anyway, so hiding/simulating the cancellation is quite simple.